# Execute function only on first button press in rshiny

Tags: r, shiny

In my shiny app, I have a `render` that I want to only execute after a radio button changes values, but only the first time this happens. Is there a way to make it reactive to the first change in value, but not subsequent ones?

Comment: I would suggest adding a minimal example to show what you want to happen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below you will find that `observeEvent` has arguments such as `ignoreInit` and `once`, I would advise that you go and have a look at the function definitions on the official website [Event handler](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/observeEvent.html). I have also added the `shinyjs` library with its `disable` function which I think is handy here.

```
rm(list=ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  radioButtons("nums", "Will Execute only Once",c("1000" = 1000,"10000" = 10000), selected = 0),
  plotOutput("Plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  v <- reactiveValues()
  observeEvent(input$nums, {
    v$data <- rnorm(input$nums) 
  },ignoreInit = TRUE, once = TRUE)

  output$Plot <- renderPlot({
    if(is.null(v$data)){
      return()
    }
    disable('nums')
    hist(v$data)
    box()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]